# PDF file generated with pyPdf won't open

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am generating a PDF file using the pyPdf library in python.

After I generate the file and I try to open it I will receive the following error: File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

If I rename the file with .txt and I open it, it will work and display what I have written in the file.

This is the code:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter
output = PdfFileWriter()
outputStream = file("/home/documet_test.pdf","wb")
outputStream.write("Hello world")
outputStream.close()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: pdf != text file. `outputStream.write("Hello world")` -> `output.write(outputStream)`

Comment: @falsetru now I can open the pdf, but the content is empty

Comment: pyPdf seems not good for generating pdf from scratch. It require another pdf to make pages. You may need to find another library like reportlab to create pdf from scratch.

Comment: If you don't post an example PDF document, it's hard to tell what might be wrong with it.

Comment: I'm writing just some string as in the example with "hello world". I need to generate it from scratch so probably I will need to use reportlab

Comment: Once more: "If you don't post an example PDF document, it's hard to tell what might be wrong with it.". There are lots of people here who understand PDF files but will not go through the trouble of setting up your environment to get a similar PDF file. If you want help debugging problems, provide the means for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reportlab library will solve the problem:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf") 
c.drawString(100,750,"Welcome to Reportlab!")
c.save()
```

Comment: to complete your answer, add the link where you find this answer: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/  and the place to get reportlab package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab ;-)